# Notation for a Probability Distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, notation

I came across this in a paper:

$$w_i\tilde{} \mathcal{CN}(0,2\sigma_{w_i}^2)$$

I am wondering what it refers to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In English: $w_i$ is drawn from a [complex normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_normal_distribution) with mean $0$ and variance $2\sigma_{w_i}^2$.

Answer (score 1):

This is the [complex normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_normal_distribution). The real and complex values of the distribution are both normally distributed.